# Dojo editor does not work in Chrome 44 in some cases

Tags: dojo

This morning my Chrome has been updated to version 44 and dojo editor widget I am using in my projects no longer works in some cases.

It seem to be working fine when used on a plain html page, but when using on modal window or inside an element with positioning the content of iframe becomes invisible due to zero width and being positioned at the left top corner of the browser.

Even dojo editor example in the documentation (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Editor.html) does not work in Chrome 44.

Any help?

Edit: as a temporary workaround, we found this solution is working for us when loading the content of an editor into iframe:

```
this.iframe.style.display = "none";
setTimeout(dojo.hitch(this, function() {
    this.iframe.style.display = "";
}), 100);
```

Comment: IMO This is a bug in chrome 44.  
It is not dojo releated. the iframe document is completely off...

Comment: BTW: Very scary but the same bug exist in Chrome 46 (Canary)

Comment: Yeah I think so too, I created a ticket in Chromium bug tracker - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=514179&thanks=514179&ts=1437998907.